# Unable to Display this Web Part when making BDC call

Tags: web-part, bdc-model, custom-bdc

I've followed along with [this Microsoft tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231515.aspx).

I can step through my code and see results returned from the database, so my Linq queries are working.

However, when I try to set up the web part, I get a message saying "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator."

This has me confused since I've recreated my project several times, and I'm positive I haven't missed any steps in the tutorial.

In the SharePoint log, there are lines about the default filter possibly causing performance issues. I've changed the throttling from 2000 (default) to 40000 items, but I think that's bogus - my table only has about 700 records, and I limit the Linq to 20 results.

Any thoughts on what's going on here and how I can correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up figuring this out with advice from another Microsoft forum. Posting a link here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

[Resolution](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/60932fd8-f605-4c29-803d-f3b96d41b36e)